# How to get EDID code for Adafruit TFP401 HDMI/DVI Decoder to support 640x480 display

Tags: lcd, adafruit

I'm a Flight simmer building my own Airbus A320 home-cockpit (call it a 10-year project). I'm currently building the MCDU (Multi-Function Control and Display Unit). This needs an LCD of roughly 5.6" or 5.7" with 4/3 aspect ratio that I can connect as a separate screen to my computer.

As far as I can see, the 5.6 Inch AT056TN53 V.1 640X480 Lcd-screen would be a perfect fit. This display has an FPC connector of 40 pins. You can find a datasheet [here](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/788923/Innolux/AT056TN53-V1/1). For 15 EUR extra it ships together with a Hdmi Vga Controle Driver ([AliExpress](https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/4001198077514.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.main.5.5dc073f7XtrqMj&algo_pvid=c3ca1109-03d0-49f8-ab23-0e3e459b9fd6&algo_exp_id=c3ca1109-03d0-49f8-ab23-0e3e459b9fd6-2&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2210000015273897232%22%7D&pdp_npi=2%40dis%21EUR%2159.5%2149.39%21%21%21%21%21%402102160416697525995307705d0748%2110000015273897232%21sea&curPageLogUid=L812COlhO7Ik)). I will probably do that to start with. But the Driver Board has a lot of connectors and features, which makes it quite bulky (it is almost as big as the display itself).

I also found the Adafruit TFP401 HDMI/DVI Decoder to 40-pin TTL Display. This board has a very small footprint, and only provides HDMI - exactly what I need. You find more info [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-tfp401-hdmi-slash-dvi-decoder-to-40-pin-ttl-display/editing-the-edid?view=all).

The Adafruit Decoder has an I2C EEPROM that stores the EDID data. By default, this is set to 800x480 resolution. But you can rewrite the I2C EEPROM to program other EDID values. The link to the card above includes the Arduino code needed to reprogram the EDID EEPROM.

But you have to know what you are doing - and I have no clue. The Adafruit website even a suggests a tool [Deltacast E-EDID editor](https://www.deltacast.tv/products/free-software/e-edid-editor) to create the EDID data needed for upload, but this tool is just a mystery for me.

Looking at the Adafruit website, showing the code to be used with Arduino, I "only" need a table of 128 bytes. Is there anybody out there that can help me, or provide me the correct data to allow connecting my 640x480 display?

```
/* Adafruit breakout @ 800x480 ! */ 
uint8_t PROGMEM eepromdat[128] = {
0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x04, 0x81, 0x04, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x01, 0x11, 0x01, 0x03, 0x80, 0x0F, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01,
0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x80, 0x0C, 0x20, 0x80, 0x30, 0xE0, 0x2D, 0x10, 0x28, 0x30,
0xD3, 0x00, 0x6C, 0x44, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x17,
};
```

Comment: Generating EDID data may not be an electrical engineering question. But yes  there are a lot of tools to generate and analyze them, even free tools. The EDID standard is also freely available for reading. You don't need HDMI EDID, a DVI EDID which fits into 128 bytes is enough. You can likely get enough info from Wikipedia EDID page.

Comment: Hello @Justme. I agree that EDID is not an electrical engineering question - but it's part of a hardware solution. That's why I thought that it is acceptable to ask the question here. More than willing to move to another forum if you could give a hint where to post this. About reading the EDID standard, thanks for the tip. I just tried to find a shortcut here - you never know people have already struggled to get the correct data, and could provide me. Yes, a bit lazy, but I have a ton of other challenges in my project, so I try to choose my battles.

Comment: Hey @HansBilliet I'm curious if you did end up using the Adafruit board with the AT056TN53 V.1. As you mention the Aliexpress board is just so chunky and I'm wanting to simplify what's in the device I'm building too. If you did get it working what EDID data did you use in the end? (and useful to know it works before I order the Adafruit driver board)